# How to lazy load?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, lazy-loading

How do you lazy load a `NSMutableArray` in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`? I am very new to Objective-C, XCode, and iOS programming, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lazy load means 'loading on demand'. So you perform operation only when it is really necessary, and not beforehand. Say we have method:

```
-(void) init {
   self = [super init];

   mMyMemberArray = [self loadSomeDataToArray];
}

-(void)  tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: {
   [someObject processData: mMyMemberArray];
}
```

This is not lazy loading cause we've loaded data beforehand. But this:

```
-(void)  tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: {
   someObject processData: [self loadSomeDataToArray]];
}
```

is exactly lazy loading, cause you get data when you really need it.